# Why is an optional object member typed as 'never'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm very confused with the following little piece of code:

```js
interface Test {
    one?: number,
    two?: {
        n: number
    }
}

const test: Test = {
    one: 1,
    two: { n: 2 }
}

function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, key: K): O[K] {
    return obj[key]
}

let x = prop(test, 'one')   // Compiles ok, x is number | undefined
let y = prop(test.two, 'n') // Argument of type '"n"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Here, `x` is typed as `number | undefined`, which is expected. But `y` is typed as `never`. Why is that? I'd expect `{ n: number } | undefined` instead.

What I am missing, and how can I make this code compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this fails is that under `strictNullChecks` is that optional fields are typed as `OriginalType | undefined`. Only common members of a union are accessible, and since `undefined` has no members this leads to the `never`.

If you type obj as `obj: O | undefined | null` this will take out the `null` from `O`

```
function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O | undefined | null, key: K): O[K] | undefined | null {
    return obj && obj[key]
}

let x = prop(test, 'one')   // number | null | undefined
let y = prop(test.two, 'n') // number | null | undefined
```

Or a version that does not introduce `null` and `undefined` unnecessarily :

```
interface Test {
    one?: number,
    two?: {
        n: number
    }
    req: {
        n: number
    }
}

const test: Test = {
    one: 1,
    two: { n: 2 },
    req: { n: 2 }
}

function prop<O, K extends keyof Exclude<O, undefined | null>>(obj: O, key: K): Extract<O, undefined | null> | Exclude<O, undefined | null>[K]
function prop<K extends PropertyKey, V>(obj: Record<K, undefined | null | V>, key: K): V | undefined | null {
    return obj && obj[key]
}

let x = prop(test, 'one')   // number | undefined
let y = prop(test.two, 'n') // number | undefined
let z = prop(test.req, 'n') // number
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the `type | undefined` thing but didn't realize its implications.  
As a side question, why doesn't TS allow the call anyway since it knows the `prop`function is called with an object that has all the members defined in the interface - even those that are optional ?

Comment: @StephanSchreiber it would allow the call, but with `K` as `never` : `prop(test.two, 'n' as never)`. But since `keyof` for unions only returns common properties the last parameter is `never` and without a type cast you can't call it.